# Paper acceptance probability in case of Minor revision after a major revision

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper in Physics background journal. At the 1st review, the referees' have written positive statement. One of the referee suggested minor revision, while the other suggested major revision. I have revised the paper according to the referees' comments. Recently. I have received minor comments (only a few text corrections) from the referee who suggested major revision at the 1st review. I have revised again the paper according to the referee comments and submitted to the journal about 2 weeks ago. However, I have received any decision letter yet. Does a minor revision after a major revision lead to acceptance ?

Comment: It seems likely to me that the paper will be accepted.  But of course it is not definite until they make their decision and notify you.

Answer (score 4):

Minor revision means most likely your article will be accepted, but it's not a guarantee. I have an experience of getting two minor revisions and finally article was rejected, othe other hand another article was accepted after major revision. 
 Bottom line, it's all depends how well you respond to reviewer comments and how much reviewer and editor get satisfy with your revised version.
 Good Luck!